# Find Sage table field

Tags: sage-erp

I’m trying to determine what Sage 300 database table & field name lies behind the field in the yellow box below? Looks like I’ve got to drive some conditional logic with it for a report, but I can’t find it in the database.
[image: Items/Taxes]

You get to it by clicking the Item/Tax button on the O/E Order Entry screen as below:-
[image: O/E Order Entry]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.